# meteor form validation using parsley

Tags: forms, validation, meteor, parsley, atmosphere.js

I have no clue how this is going, I have followed the steps on meteor parsley package.

I want the form not the get submitted if there is no valid input. though it show undefined when added for the url, but I want to restrict form from submitting until it satisfies the condition.

> ```
> <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="addItem" data-parsley-validate>    
> <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
>   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" 
>          for="sm">Listing URL</label>
>   <div class="col-sm-3">
>     <input  type="url" 
>             class="form-control" 
>             id="listing_url" 
>             placeholder="Enter the listing URL"
>             data-required='true'
>             data-type='url'
>             data-trigger='change'/> 
>   </div>
> </div>
> <div class="container ">
>     <div class="panel-footer"> 
>         <button class="btn btn-danger btn-md">Clear</button>
>         <button class="btn btn-success btn-md pull-right submit">Submit</button>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

```
    Template.addItem.events({
  'click .submit': function() {
    var current_date = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm");
    var insertform = {
      created_at: current_date,
      url: $('#url').val()
    }
        console.log('insertform:', insertform);
        insertForm.insert(insertform);    
  }
})
Template.addItem.onRendered = (function () {
  // Setup parsley form validation
  // replace form with the id of your form
  $('#addItem').parsley({trigger: 'change'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the form's valid and then run your submit code.

```
    var formValid = $('#addItem').parsley('validate')
    if (formValid)
    {
        var current_date = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm");
        var insertform = {
            created_at: current_date,
            url: $('#url').val()
         }
        console.log('insertform:', insertform);
        insertForm.insert(insertform); 
    }
```

Comment: hey prabhu thanks but it still doesnt work, it still sends the data into the database.